# How does Imagemagick handle a character that is not in the specified font?

Tags: imagemagick

We're using Imagemagick 6.6.3 to embed Chinese characters into an image. A few of the characters are appearing as ?.

Does Imagemagick use a default font for characters that are not in the specified font?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Imagemagick have a fall back for missing characters.

On the following site you can find this information: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

> Rather than a question mark, many fonts would just print a box or a
>   blank character for such undefined characters. If you see too many
>   such characters, or missing characters in your output, you probably
>   should be using a different font.